# Does ESD protection cause voltage leakage?

Tags: esp32, protection, esd, leakage-current, tp4056

[image]

I have a this schematic for powering ESP32 over the usb and communicate PC with usb interface. It works perfect. But there is a interesting error. while I am powering ESP32 with Lipo battery (In case of a power outage) there is a 2~3 volt seen on [USBLC6](https://ozdisan.com/Product/Detail/402751/USBLC6-2SC6)' 5th pin (VUSB). Normally it is impossible because there is no connection between VUSB (USBLC6' 5th pin) and VBUS (tp4056's output). I have step by step remove parts on pcb and tested there is a voltage on VUSB side until removing USBLC6 on pcb. if I remove the ESD protection [USBLC6 module](https://ozdisan.com/Product/Detail/402751/USBLC6-2SC6), leakege voltage disappearing.

This comes to my mind: Is there a leakage voltage across the usb_DP and usb_DN pins of the ESP32?

this is my lipo battery circuit:
[image]

Comment: Do you have the circuit on a ready pcb, or on breadboard right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider my amendments to your diagram: -

[image]

Because of the inherent connection shown in blue there will be currents flowing from the data lines via the ESD protection diodes that can put a residual voltage onto \$V_{USB}\$. This means that the residual voltage will be seen on the fifth pin of your connector.

Comment: Thanks your brilliant answer. Are there any solution

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a solution to a problem that might not exist.

Comment: Very nice .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. It could also leak through D3(M7) or through charging module with mystery circuitry in it.

The problem is, that design violates rules of USB peripherals.

USB peripheral must know when USB host applies 5V and when not in order to control the USB pins to known state.

For normal ESP that is only powered through USB and via no other power source, there is nothing that can go wrong - when USB 5V is present it can pull data lines up, and when USB 5V is absent, there is no power so it can't do anything.

In your case, the ESP is powered via battery, and the ESP does not know if USB 5V is present or not, or if there is even anything plugged in to USB connector. And it still keeps USB pins pulled up while it should not.

Converting a bus powered design to a self powered design must be done correctly.